# MySQL Table Normalizing via plain sql error

Tags: mysql, normalizing

I need to normalize my table. So I made a script (sql) which I execute.
I would like to INSERT all existing Clients from table A (old) into table B (new).

It is simply done with

```
INSERT INTO `A` SELECT * FROM `B`;
```

but I want to set some foreign key values. There is a `city` field in table `A` but a `city_id`field in table `B`.  I thought of something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `A` (`id`, `name`, `city_id`)
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `B`,
(SELECT `cities`.`id` FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`name` = (SELECT `city` FROM `A` WHERE `A`.`id` = `B`.`id`)) `temp_cities`;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because `B`.`id` isn't set :-( The error is the following:

```
Error (1054): Unknown column 'B.id' in 'where clause')
```

At which point did I mess something up?

Comment: Please show the schemas of the tables.

Comment: Simplified (because the other stuff doesn't matter):
A { id, name, city }
B { id, name, city_id }
cities { id, name }

Answer (score 0):

just use syntax SELECT id **AS 'city_id'** FROM B , you can 'name' each column in your select and then you can insert it without any issues.

You can deactivate foreign keys constraint like this :

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

and switch it back to

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

after you finish query. It`s not best practice but sometimes it can help.

Comment: I don't know, if you understand what my problem is: I need to replace `B`.`id` (in the 2nd derived SELECT query) with the id of the current's INSERT row.